Deployment Failure of SAM Code for S3 and Lambda Using Cross-Stack References
I wrote SAM code to create S3 and Lambda resources, but the deployment failed.
Could you help me identify what went wrong?
Error Message:
AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31 is null

Project Structure:
s3Lambda/
│-- functions
│   └-- app.py
│-- templates/
│   │-- root-template.yaml
│   │-- s3.yaml
│   └-- lambda.yaml
└-- parameters/
    └-- samconfig.yaml


File Details:
templates/root-template.yaml:
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Parameters:
  BucketName:
    Type: String
    Description: "The name of the S3 Bucket"
  FunctionName:
    Type: String
    Description: "The name of the Lambda function"
  FunctionTimeout:
    Type: Number
    Description: "The maximum time in seconds that the function can run before it is stopped"
    Default: 3
  FunctionMemorySize:
    Type: Number
    Description: "The size of the memory in MB allocated per invocation of the function"

Resources:
  S3Stack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: ./s3.yaml
      Parameters:
        BucketName: !Ref BucketName

  LambdaStack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    DependsOn:
      - S3Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: ./lambda.yaml
      Parameters:
        FunctionName: !Ref FunctionName
        FunctionTimeout: !Ref FunctionTimeout
        FunctionMemorySize: !Ref FunctionMemorySize

Outputs:
  S3BucketName:
    Description: Name of the S3 bucket
    Value: !GetAtt S3Stack.Outputs.S3BucketName

  S3BucketArn:
    Description: "S3 Bucket ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt S3Stack.Outputs.S3BucketArn

  MyS3LambdaFunctionArn:
    Description: "The ARN of the Lambda Function"
    Value: !GetAtt LambdaStack.Outputs.MyS3LambdaFunctionArn


templates/s3.yaml:
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: s3
Parameters:
  BucketName:
    Type: String
    Description: "The name of the S3 Bucket"

Resources:
  MyS3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref BucketName
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref BucketName

Outputs:
  S3BucketName:
    Description: Name of the S3 bucket
    Value: !Ref MyS3Bucket
    Export:
      Name: MyS3BucketName
  S3BucketArn:
    Description: "S3 Bucket ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt MyS3Bucket.Arn
    Export:
      Name: MyS3BucketArn


templates/lambda.yaml:
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: Lambda function triggered by S3 events

Parameters:
  FunctionName:
    Type: String
    Description: "The name of the Lambda function"
  FunctionTimeout:
    Type: Number
    Description: "The maximum time in seconds that the function can run before it is stopped"
    Default: 3
  FunctionMemorySize:
    Type: Number
    Description: "The size of the memory in MB allocated per invocation of the function"

Resources:
  MyS3LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref FunctionName
      CodeUri: ../functions/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.12
      MemorySize: !Ref FunctionMemorySize
      Timeout: !Ref FunctionTimeout
      Policies:
        - S3WritePolicy:
            BucketName: !ImportValue MyS3BucketName
      Events:
        S3Event:
          Type: S3
          Properties:
            Bucket: !ImportValue MyS3BucketName
            Events: s3:ObjectCreated:*
      Tags:
        Name: !Ref FunctionName

Outputs:
  MyS3LambdaFunctionArn:
    Description: "The ARN of the Lambda Function"
    Value: !GetAtt MyS3LambdaFunction.Arn
    Export:
      Name: MyS3LambdaFunctionArn


I want to know if it's possible to create S3 and Lambda using cross-stack references with AWS SAM. If it's possible, I would like to know how to fix it.

The root issue arises because your nested lambda.yaml template specifies the AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31 transform, but CloudFormation doesn’t automatically process nested templates with the SAM transform.
When you nest templates, SAM treats the nested templates as regular CloudFormation templates. CloudFormation doesn’t process the SAM transform in a nested stack. so, you cannot directly use the AWS::Serverless::Function resource type in a nested stack.
The solution for this is either move the AWS::Serverless::Function definition from lambda.yaml into your root template so the SAM transform processes it. Or replace AWS::Serverless::Function with AWS::Lambda::Function
